# ActiveAdmin Ratyrate unable to find current_user OR Alternative

Tags: authentication, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, rating-system

I have been trying to integrate [raytrate](https://github.com/wazery/ratyrate) into ActiveAdmin when trying to include the partial into my Activeadmin supply_company.rb it apears to be unable to find the 'current_user'. I know that with a standard install of ActiveAdmin and devise I have left the admin user as admin_user so should be able to use current_admin_user to set the current user. I have a suspicion it the way in which I'm trying to include the render in the sidebar.

*Or if anyone has an alternative model for rating that they know works in ActiveAdmin I would gladly take a look at it*.

**The error message is** 
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `current_user' for #<#:0x6b50a58>):

**app/controllers_rater_controller.rb**

```
class RaterController < ApplicationController

  def create
    if admin_user_signed_in?
      obj = params[:klass].classify.constantize.find(params[:id])
      obj.rate params[:score].to_f, current_admin_user, params[:dimension]

      render :json => true
    else
      render :json => false
    end
  end
end
```

**app/models/admin_user.rb**

```
class AdminUser < ActiveRecord::Base

 rolify
  has_one :profile, foreign_key: :admin_user_id
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile

  has_many :addresses
  has_many :address_types, :through => :addresses

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses

  ratyrate_rater

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, 
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => 
  "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

end
```

**app/models/supply_companies.rb**

```
class SupplyCompany < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :products, :through => :product_supply_companies
  has_many :product_supply_companies, :foreign_key => 'supply_company_id'

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :products
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_supply_companies, :allow_destroy => true

  ratyrate_rateable "communication", "quality", "price"
end
```

/app/admin/supply_company.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.register SupplyCompany do
   permit_params :id, :company_name,
                 products_attributes: [:id, :product_name, :product_description],
                 product_supply_companies_attributes: [:id, :product_id],
                 supply_company_ratings_attributes: [:id, :admin_user_id, :supply_company_id, :supply_company_rating ],
                 admin_user_attributes: [:id]
  index do
    column :id
    column :company_name
    column :products do |pt|
      pt.products.collect {|c| c.product_name.capitalize }.to_sentence
    end
    actions
  end

filter :company_name

   form(:html => {:multipart => true}) do |f|
     f.inputs "Company Details" do
     f.input :company_name
     end
     f.actions
   end
   show title: :company_name do
     attributes_table do
       row :company_name
     end
     end

  sidebar "Products", only: :show do
    attributes_table_for supply_company do
      row "Ratings" do
        render  'supply_company_ratings'
      end
      row :products do |pt|
        pt.products.collect {|c| link_to c.product_name.capitalize, admin_products_path + "\/" + c.id.to_s}.join(", ").html_safe
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**app/views/admin/supply_companies/_supply_companines_ratings.html.erb**

```
<h2>Communication  :</h2> <%= rating_for @supply_company, "communication" %>
<h2>Engine :</h2> <%= rating_for @supply_company, "quality" %>
<h2>Price  :</h2> <%= rating_for @supply_company, "price" %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sound's like you have installed ratyrate with `rails g ratyrate user`, you need to install it with `rails g ratyrate admin_user`.